# How to filter out nonexistent object that a foreign key is pointing to

Tags: django, django-models

I have model that has a relationship to another model through a foreign key called person. The model looks like:

```
class PR(models.Model):
    p_keyid   = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    r_no      = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    person    = models.ForeignKey('person.Person', db_column = 'person_no')
    recall_dt = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        managed  = False
        db_table = 'person_r'
```

Note that the "managed" Meta is false (and it is not a table that I created).

Sometimes there is a `person_no` value in the `person_r` table that does not exist. For example, a `PR.person` has a value of 232. However, the person with id 232 does not exist (foreign key is pointing to a an object that does not exist). How can I filter *out* such bad PR instances?

In my view I have this:

```
 r_for_date = PR.objects.filter(recall_dt__range = (startdate, enddate)
```

and I do want `r_for_date` to contain records with person attribute that do not exist (in the example above, that record with person id of 232 should not show up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that solution will help you:

`r_for_date = PR.objects.filter(person__id__isnull=False,recall_dt__range = (startdate, enddate))`

Besause `person__id` belongs to `person` table.

But it will be better when you define this filter in manager

```
class PRManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    return super(PRManager, self).get_queryset().filter(person__id__isnull=False)
```

That allows you not add `person__id__isnull=False` to each filter. Hope that'll help you. Please tell me about results after you trying this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do..

```
valid_people_ids = Person.objects.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
bad_pr_people = PR.objects.exclude(person_id__in=valid_people_ids)
```

Hope that helps.